# Conditional CSS for scrolling background breaks on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

NOTE: this is not homework, it is just a site to display my assignment.

I'm using this nice tip:
http://css-tricks.com/3d-parralax-background-effect/

to add a scrolling star field to my college game project.

http://asteroids.chrisloughnane.net/

and naturally my lecturer was using Firefox so he got back to me saying its not working.

It works fine in 
Chrome
Safari
IE9

I would like to have some conditional CSS to either

a. just put a background of my choice on Firefox

or

b. implement the scrolling field in Firefox

I've searching here and online and couldn't find anything.

tia

The CSS that is causing the problem is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes STAR-MOVE {
    from {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    to { 
        left: -10000px;
        top: -2000px;
    }
}

#background {
    background: black url(../images/background.png) repeat 5% 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;

    -webkit-animation-name: STAR-MOVE;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 200s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#midground {
    background: url(../images/midground.png) repeat 20% 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 200;

    -webkit-animation-name: STAR-MOVE;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 150s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#foreground {
    background: url(../images/foreground.png) repeat 35% 35%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 300;

    -webkit-animation-name: STAR-MOVE;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 100s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
-moz-animation-name:mymove;
-moz-animation-duration:150s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like firefox is using own prefix `-moz-animation-name` etc.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-name.asp

Hope this will work.